# Mixin for using variable fonts

Tags: css, fonts, sass

Possibly insoluble Sass/CSS problem: I am using a variable font but Chrome currently only supports `font-variation-settings` rather than being able to use `font-weight`, `font-style` etc I still want to use `font-weight` etc for old browsers that don’t support variable fonts.

I don't want to have to type out two properties everytime I set a font-style or font-weight! So I came up with some mixins:

```
@mixin font-weight($weight) {
    font-variation-settings: "wght" $weight;
    font-weight: $weight;
}

@mixin oblique($angle) {
    font-variation-settings: "slnt" $angle;
    font-style: oblique #{$angle + deg};
}
```

Obviously I will sometimes want to use both font-weight *and* oblique and you can’t set the same CSS property twice - it will just get overridden. So I came up with this

```
@mixin font-weight($weight) {
    --weight: #{$weight};
    font-variation-settings: "wght" var(--weight), "slnt" var(--angle, 0);
    font-weight: $weight;
}

@mixin oblique($angle) {
    --angle: #{$angle};
    font-variation-settings: "slnt" var(--angle), "wght" var(--weight, 400);
    font-style: oblique #{$angle + deg};
}
```

which kinda works except that defaulting to font-weight 400 isn’t ok - that is the default normal weight of browsers, but it doesn’t account for the fact that I will have probably set the font-weight somewhere else. I could just half give-up and make it a single mixin `@mixin weight-and-oblique($weight, $oblique)` but that is a horrible API to work with imo. Is there a solution?

Comment: It defaults to 400 only when you _didn't_ use the font-weight mixin on the same element, or a parent. If you have set the weight to something else, then the `--weight` variable will carry that custom value and will be applied by the oblique mixin if you use it. This should work nicely (I'm using the same mechanism on the generated CSS in https://wakamaifondue.com)